# Not my Rich Snippets

Tags: seo, rich-snippets

My client had discussed in depth SEO. It was put off, however. Recently though, a Google search of the site revealed rich snippets. This is not from work that I have done for the site. I had began to work on this for his site, but it was put off and never made it into the deployments.

How could the site possibly have rich snippets. If it is not from me, where could it be coming from?

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information than this. What rich snippet is being displayed?

Comment: Sorry if I was vague. Business and Organization Snippets. Just 2 columns and 3 rows of links. I've not used this snippet before, so I'm not so familiar with the exact terms here. It's definitely reminiscent of a e-commerce site's SEO.

Comment: Your client figured out how to implement it themselves, or hired somebody else to do it in the meantime?

Comment: It happens sometimes that such "discussions" result in them feeling that they have gathered enough information to pass it to some internal guy to make SEO changes. To avoid this, have a contract ready from the beginning to charge for even basic consultations even before most of the work has started or was agreed upon.

Comment: Be prepared because customers will disappoint you. It is sad too. You think that most people are honorable and honest, but some see nothing wrong with using you to get ahead. That may be the case here, though admittedly to a lesser degree. I am sorry. Just learn to structure your discussions in the future to not give away your best secrets. Hold your cards close to your chest.

Comment: Or the internal guy knows their business model and marketing focus a lot better than an outside third party and they implemented it themselves. I've been in SEO discussions where I've been told "I was just looking at your website" only to find they had a profound lack of knowledge either of our website or our true business focus. If you're not in their industry, they may also feel that they need somebody with an actual direct interest, knowledge and experience to properly implement their SEO. Most SEO is knowledgeable copywriting, not keyword plugging.

Comment: It was likely Google+

Comment: @Fiasco Labs makes a valid point. SEO is difficult enough. But knowing the industry is also an important factor that has to be overcome. For SEOs it can pay to know certain industries extremely well and know specifically how to help them. Sometimes, you have to be a member of the club, so to speak, to really understand it.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I really appreciate it. I'm not too concerned about this right now. I had a discussion with him, he has no clue who did it, and I'll take him at his word - mainly because I know him. He knows nothing about SEO nor does he have time to bother with a discussion over it. If he did seek help elsewhere, I'm still not too concerned. He is a VERY difficult client to manage, and I am desperately trying to remove some of the dependence he has on me, because I have other clients as well. None the less, thank you for the help. It will allow me to be more aware for the future.